# hql query outer join

Tags: java, hibernate, iterator, hql

Hi everyone I am trying to do an outer join using hql and iterate the retrieved columns to display it.
the code below shows no error and also no outputs.

```html
<html>
<body>
<%
           try {
    SessionFactory sf=  new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session s= sf.openSession();
    Query e=s.createQuery("select u.*, d.* from Units u,Depts d outer join d.deptId=u.depts");
    Iterator i= e.iterate();
            out.println("<table>");
            while(i.hasNext())
            { 
            Units l= (Units)i.next();
            Depts v= (Depts)i.next();;
            out.println("<tr><th>"+l.getUnitId());
            out.println("<th>"+v.getDeptName());
            out.println("<th>"+l.getUnitName());
            }
            } catch (Exception he) {
                he.printStackTrace();}
        %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look into logs. You may find errors there. Your sql is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Correct SQL is

```
select u.*, d.* from Units u outer join Depts d on d.deptId=u.depts
```